# Unable to set password of myphpadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The solutions those posts stated:

- Adhere to the password policy.
- uninstall plugin validate_password (which I don't want to do )

My password policy:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
```

Now I don't know what will satisfy the MySQL password validation plugin, I tried a ton of passwords that had all the requirements stated below, like
`Ml9506&#`, `Qwerty123!@#`, `qwertyQWERTY098)(*` and a ton of more passwords.

I got this error while installing PHPMyAdmin:

```
MySQL ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

I also tried changing the policy to `LOW` but that also didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set policy level to low.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;
```

OR

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=0;
```

check password validation policy level with:

```
$ SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

If the password policy doesn't change, exit from the MySQL prompt and restart the MySQL service from your Terminal window:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

then go to MySQL and create your user

Comment: What do you mean by *"check it set truly"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69602163/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).